# Dynamically change input type

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 2.2. I am trying to build an exam system. Some questions have 1 right answer, others have multiple right answers. According to this, my view should show radio buttons or checkboxes. I have one hard coded example in my XHTML page:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{main.answerList}" var="list">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxAnswer" value="#{list.check}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{list.ansValue}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

How can I change between radio buttons and checkboxes, depending on the question type?

Comment: Why don't you put both and have only one rendered ? Edit (to reformulate it as an answer): I would suggest that you put both (selectOneRadio and selectManyCheckbox) and only render one depending on the number of right answers.

Comment: @subodh: please stop formatting non-code as code. Library/framework/entity names are not code!

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question... please don't assume that we understand your business requirements, just try to explain your technical problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `rendered` attribute to toggle between the input types depending on the question type. The code (the variable names) in your question is not self-documenting, so I'm making changes on that as well, so that it becomes more self-documenting and it's immediately obvious what each of those properties represent.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.questions}" var="question">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{question.selectedAnswer}" rendered="#{question.type == 'SINGLE_CHOICE'}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{question.availableAnswers}" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{question.selectedAnswers}" rendered="#{question.type == 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE'}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{question.availableAnswers}" />
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The `#{question.type}` should represent an `enum` with the mentioned values.

Comment: Should I write the special converter for this enum?

Comment: No. They're evaluated as string.